# DIV will not disappear on small screen

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have tried many different ways and nothing have worked.

I wanted to make the DIV disappear on screen smaller than 499px.

```
div.navND {
    display: none;
}

div.navNM {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    div.navND {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
    div.navNM {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    div.navNM {
        display: none;
    }
}
```

Could anyone help me fixing this problem.

Thank you

Comment: If you can, providing the HTML may help in getting a useful answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you all for the help,

With you help I started changing things around and it worked.

**error**
if I changed the display to block instead of none:

```
div.navND {
    display: block;
}

div.navNM {
    display: block;
}
```

Both div would be shown, but I wanted just one at the time or none.

Here is the solution to my problem:

```
/*---------------*/
.navND {
    display: none;
}

.navNM {
    display: none;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    div.navND {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 749px) {
    div.navNM {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}

@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    div.navNM {
        clear: both;
        display: none;
    }
}
```

The error was the "min-width"

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
@media screen and (min-width: 500px) {
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (max-width: 499px) {
    div#id { 
        display:none;
    }
}
```

I believe that should make the div with the given #id disappear at 499 and below. So if you want it to still be visible at 499 just change it to 498.

http://jsfiddle.net/y6gffrp6/1/

^ in that example I used 700 as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Testing you css code in JSFiddle give us what we expect

http://jsfiddle.net/p3dtkj2j/

i don't understand why you put this

```
@media screen and (min-width: 750px) {
    div.navND {
        clear: both;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

just make it display:block by default

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/huander/vbqv3q2j/

Here is the code, but it is PHP from wordpress.

Just for you to have an idea.

Comment: the site is [link](http://paleoall.com) and I want the google adsense at the navbar to disappear when screen is smaller than 499px.

Comment: as i see between 720px and 500px it's not showing when go under 500 it return.
try removing all the @media screen and (min-width: blabla)

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p3dtkj2j/1/ : display:block by default and none in in screen and (max-width)